# Creating List from Linq filter

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently filtering out a List populated by JSON data :

```
List<RootObject> FlightTimes = (List<RootObject>)GridView1.DataSource;
foreach (var v in from p in FlightTimes
                  where p.Direction == "A"
                  select new { p.Date, p.Time, p.SortTime, p.Direction, p.FlightNumber, p.Endpoint, p.Status, p.Status2 }) ;
```

I'm having trouble trying to get the data from the foreach into a new list. Can anybody help with this?

Comment: whats the problem? whats the error? what have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure where to start with it ive not used linq before.

Comment: what do you want to do? if you don't know how to use linq you should read a linq tutorial. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: `RootObject` doesn't seem a very descriptive name for a class which appears to hold details of a flight. There might be good reason for it but if not you might want to rethink that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your loop produces elements of an anonymous type, so you cannot declare a properly typed list for it. You can solve this problem by not using `foreach`, and sending the results of the query to `ToList`:

```
var myList = (
    from p in FlightTimes
    where p.Direction == "A"
    select new {
        p.Date
    ,   p.Time
    ,   p.SortTime
    ,   p.Direction
    ,   p.FlightNumber
    ,   p.Endpoint
    ,   p.Status
    ,   p.Status2
    }
).ToList();
```

Now compiler has enough information to capture the type of the list, producing the result that you expect. If you need to perform additional processing in a loop, use `myList` in a separate `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get a list of the objects which have `Direction == "A"` you can refactor it down to this:

```
var FlightTimes = ((List<RootObject>)GridView1.DataSource)
    .Where(ft => ft.Direction == "A").ToList();
```